# Selenium webDriver - Submenu clicks only when IE browser is in resized state(not maximized state)

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Selenium WebDriver -> sub menu link is not clicking when the IE browser is in maximized state. but works fine when i set the IE browser to smaller size (drag it and make smaller window)

can someone please suggest what needs to be done..

Comment: what error do you getting when use max. view of IE and try to click on link?

Comment: No error message , test is passing. but submenu page not loading..  when ie is not maximized sub menu page is loading properly... Same is works fine by clicking manually with maximized window.

Comment: can you please share your webdriver code and html code where you are working?

Comment: Not information for us to help you.

Comment: 'WebElement ic =  driver.findElement(By.linkText("Presentations"));
'Actions act = new Actions(driver);
'act.moveToElement(ic).build().perform();
' 
' //ic.click();
' 
'  
'//driver.findElement(By.linkText("Hypothetical")).click();
'// 'driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2[@id='presentations']/a[1]")).click();
' WebElement hyp=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@id='leftMenuElement']/div/a[1]'[@id'='hypothetical'] "));
' // act.moveToElement(hyp).click().perform();
' hyp.click();